# How do I end the program using ctrl z only

Tags: c++

When I type characters instead of numbers on the 2nd line after typing "add", my program will end the input even if I haven't used ctrl-z. Is there any way for my program to only recognize ctrl-z as the one to end inputs?

The program I'm trying to do is an adder with a non-interactive interface and an interactive one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

// Solving function
void solve(string str) {
// declare stream for string str
istringstream ss(str);

// declare word, num, and sum variables
string word;
float num = 0, sum = 0;

// set while loop to continue checking until break
while(ss >> word) {
    // removes the input "add" from the equation
    if (word != "add") {
        // stream converts string word to float
        stringstream stream1(word);

        // sets the floating point number as the variable num's value
        stream1 >> num;

        // performs addition
        sum = sum + num;
}
    }
// if the only argument is "add" the addition returns 0
if (sum== 0 && num == 0) {
    // print instructions
    cout << "Type numbers to be added, 1 per line. Ctrl-Z to end input.\n";

    // declare variables needed
    float dig = 0, total = 0;

    // set another while loop to keep checking for input
    while(true) {
        // if input is CTRL + Z, print the total and break out of the while loop
        if (cin.eof()){
            cout << total;
            break;
        } else {
            // perform addition first, then set digit variable's value
            total = total + dig;
            cin >> dig;
        }
    }
} else {
    cout << sum;
}
}

     // main function
     int main()
{
    string input;
    string arg;

    getline(cin, input);

    stringstream inputStream (input);
    inputStream >> arg;

    if (arg == "add") {
    solve(input);
}

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: There is no header called `stream` in the standard library. You probably meant `sstream`.  ... and use the C++ header `cstdlib` instead of the C header `stdlib.h`.

Comment: Oh, i changed it just now, thank you for that

Comment: You're welcome. You're still using `stdlib.h` though.